# Return a custom error message for 400 requests that don't hit the controller

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-400

I need to be able to return a custom error message for requests that are Bad Requests, but don't hit a controller (ex. Having bad JSON). Does anyone have any idea how to go about this? I tried the @ExceptionHandler annotation to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If they don't hit a controller, surely the correct status code is 404?

Comment: JamesB, no. Bad JSON coming from client gets rejected with a HTTP 400 by the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Spring 3.2 you can add a ControllerAdvice like this

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ControllerAdvice
public class BadRequestHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorBean handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        ErrorBean errorBean = new ErrorBean();
        errorBean.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return errorBean;
    }

    class ErrorBean {
        private String message;

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

In `handleHttpMessageNotReadableException`, which is annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)`, you can handle the exception and render a custom response. In this case a ErrorBean becomes populated and return to the client. If `Jackson` is available on classpath and `Content-Type` was set to `application/json` by the client, this ErrorBean gets returned as json.